# Extra actions after order saved

Tags: orders, save, web-services

I am new to Magento, but what I need to do is:

after the order is saved, I have to call an external webservice and pass some order data to this service.

Where or what is the best place to do so?

thanks in advance

Comment: Which magento version? Every time order saved (create/update) or after place order?

Answer (score 0):

Create custom module and call your method in sales_order_place_after event
For example
Your module xml

```
<events>
    <sales_order_place_after>
        <observers>
            <your_module_event_handler_name>
                <class>your_module/observer</class>
                <method>extraAction</method>
            </your_module_event_handler_name>
        </observers>
    </sales_order_place_after> 
</events>
```

Your function

```
public function extraAction(Varien_Event_Observer $observer) {
    $order = $observer->getEvent()->getOrder();
    // your code here
}
```